# Expectation of product of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

I'm stuck trying to show $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ for $X, Y$ nonnegative bounded independent random variables on a probability space. The definition of independence is that $P(\{ X \in B\} \cap \{ Y \in C\}) = P(X \in B) P(Y \in C)$ for Borel sets $B$ and $C$. I'm not assuming $X$ or $Y$ have probability density functions so I cannot use them. Nor can I use conditional expectation.

Comment: What is the convolution of two random variables?

Comment: It is just the convolution of the variables thought of as functions.

Comment: Functions of what?

Comment: A random variable is a function from a space to the real line. The space has a measure on an associated $\sigma$ algebra. The random variable, as a function, is measurable.

Comment: Yes.  But what is the convolution?  How is it expressed?

Comment: $$X * Y (y) = \int_\Omega X(x)Y(x-y) dP(x)$$ where $P$ is the probability measure.

Comment: What is $x-y$ when $x,y\in\Omega$?

Comment: Its foolishness on my part. I somehow assumed there was a vector space involved when it is not... I've edited the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If two random variables $X,Y$ have a joint distribution then they are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_random_variables) if and only if the corresponding CDF's satisfy: $$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)\tag1$$
Here $(1)$ is a necessary but also sufficient condition for:$$\mathsf P_{X,Y}=\mathsf P_X\times \mathsf P_Y$$where $\mathsf P_{X,Y}$ denotes the probability on $(\mathbb R^2,\mathcal B^2)$ induced by $(X,Y):\Omega\to\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathsf P_X,\mathsf P_Y$ denote the probabilities on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ induced by $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ and $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$.

Then under suitable conditions: $$\mathsf EXY=\int xydF_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int\int xydF_X(x)dF_Y(y)=\int xdF_X(x)\int ydF_Y(y)=\mathsf EX\mathsf EY$$

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints for this classical result:

Start with $X = 1_A$, $Y = 1_B$, with $A$ and $B$ borel sets.

Then, use the fact that any positive random variable $X$ can be written as : $X = \sum_{k\geq 0}{b_k 1_{B_k}}$ with $b_k$ being some positive real numbers and $B_k$ borel sets. Prove the equality for any positive random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Finally write $X = X_+ - X_-$, $Y = Y_+ - Y_-$ and conclude.

Comment: Have you studied Fubini's Theorem? Your result is the most elementary application of that theorem.